# Delete duplicates in a list, depending on the sequence of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Below, `list` is a representative sample of my list, which contains lists of integers.  I would like to be able to input:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3}};
f[list]
```

and obtain the output:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}
```

In other words, `{3, 2, 1}` is considered to be the same as `{1, 2, 3}`, since in reverse it is exactly `{1, 2, 3}`.  However, `{2, 1, 3}` is **not** considered to be the same as either `{1, 2, 3}` or `{3, 2, 1}`, because it does not match these lists in forward or in reverse.

What function `f` can I use to accomplish this?

I tried this:

```
DeleteDuplicates[list, MemberQ[list, #] || MemberQ[Reverse /@ list, #] &]
```

but it does not work, although I'm not sure why.

**ADDENDUM**

Now suppose I want to input:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

and obtain:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}};
```

where the "second" `{1, 2, 3}` is removed as a "normal" duplicate.  How can I do this?  I could do:

```
DeleteDuplicates[DeleteDuplicates[list, (#1 == Reverse[#2] &)]]
```

but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
DeleteDuplicates[list, SameQ[#1, #2] || SameQ[#1, Reverse@#2] &]
```

Comment: This is what I want. For list = `{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};`, it gives `{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If your application allows for reversed elements to be interchangeable you can do this:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort[{#, Reverse@#}][[1]] & /@ list]
```

The advantage here is speed; this is perhaps two orders of magnitude faster on large sets than the methods already presented.

Comment: This code works like a charm!! So fast! Not two orders faster, my test shows that it is at least three orders faster! It is necessary for large list. Thank you for your answer, Mr. Wizard! It solves my problem.

Comment: @matheorem As always I'm glad I could help, and thanks for letting me know you found this three-year-old post useful.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** in versions 10+, you can use [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html?q=DeleteDuplicatesBy):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Union[{#, Reverse@#}]&]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}

**Original answer:**

You can use your condition directly

```
 DeleteDuplicates[list, (#1 == Reverse[#2] &)]
```

or use `Union` with `SameTest`

```
 Union[list, SameTest -> (#1 == Reverse[#2] &)]
```

Edit: For the new requirement, you need to `Or` the conditions for "sameness" (as in @acl's answer)

```
 DeleteDuplicates[list, (#1 == Reverse[#2] || #1 == #2 &)]
 Union[list, SameTest -> (#1 == Reverse[#2] || #1 == #2&)]
```

Comment: Okay, I think they both work now. Thanks.

Comment: But now if `list = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}` we get the duplicate element twice!

Comment: @acl: Right, this is not what I wanted to happen, but I failed to specify this requirement in my original post. Please see my edit above.

Comment: @Andrew I think my answer does do this in a simple way