# Delete permutations of subtables in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got a table of tables: $A=\{\{a,b\},\{b,a\},...,\{a,b,c,d,e\},\{e,d,c,a,b\},...\}$.
How do I do to remove backward duplicates, or more generally permutations of duplicates in the table?

For example in $A$ I want to erase one of $\{a,b\},\{b,a\}$, and $\{a,b,c,d,e\},\{e,d,c,a,b\}$. Which could be the shortest way to do that? I don't mind which is the erased element...

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[list, Sort@#1 == Sort@#2 &]` - and don't use uppercase initials for your own symbols (like `A`)...

Comment: DeleteDuplicates[Sort/@A] looks like it would be faster, if you don't mind the sub lists being sorted afterwards.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(44)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44/121).  Related: [(1302)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/121), [(5799)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5799/121),
[(17041)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17041/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something as simple as

```
data = {{a, b}, {b, a}, {a, b, c, d, e}, {e, d, c, a, b}};
Union[Sort /@ data]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
> ```

Comment: Keep it small and simple... +1!

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
lst = {{a, b}, {b, a}, {a, b, c, d, e}, {e, d, c, a, b}};
DeleteDuplicates[Sort/@lst]
(* {{a, b}, {a, b, c, d, e}} *)
```